# WAR file works in tomcat but gives UTF-8 errors in Jetty, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, utf-8, jetty

I have Java webapp that I developed locally with m2eclipse + Jetty + eclipse, and deploy nightly to Tomcat.  With Jetty, I get `UTF-8 error`, when I send AJAX posts to the server. The same code works fine in tomcat.

On the Jetty side, I can see all the post parameters, and everything gets logged to the log files, but then a run time exception is thrown saying that the encoding is unrecognized.

My pages are all encoded as UTF-8, and the headers in the Post are UTF-8.  It appears that something in Jetty or Eclipse doesn't like the utf-8 encoding and I can't figure out what it might be.

any thoughts?

update:
here is a stacktrace.

```
[Click] [error] java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF-8;org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF-8;
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.setError(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:295)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.handleAjaxException(ClickServlet.java:1972)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.handleException(ClickServlet.java:458)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.handleRequest(ClickServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.click.ClickServlet.doPost(ClickServlet.java:294)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF-8;
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:42)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.getConverter(HttpWriter.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.UncheckedPrintWriter.write(UncheckedPrintWriter.java:271)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Have you tried googling for "jetty utf8"? Many other people have similar questions....

Comment: Even if you don't understand the error message, quoting it exactly in your question sure makes it easier for someone who does to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer to my question.  I am using the apache click framework and had recently upgraded from version 2.2.0 to 2.3.0-RC1.  A bug was introduced in version 2.3.0-RC1 that caused duplicate contentType headers to be sent on AJAX requests.  Tomcat was able to gracefully handle the mis-constructed header, Jetty was not.

i ended up applying a temp patch by overriding the problem function.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF-8;
> ```

That semicolon is suspicious. It isn't part of the normal error message/trace.

Sure that you or Ajax didn't set `Content-Type` to `text/html;charset=UTF-8;` or something? Use a HTTP request tracker like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to be sure. I would consider it as another ugly bug in Jetty though. It is apparently not expecting more than two attributes in the header. If you like Jetty, [report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY) it to the Jetty guys.